# Read 24 Vac signal with a Raspberry Pi

Tags: ac, raspberry-pi, opto-isolator, rectifier, 24v

I want to read a 24 Vac signal coming from my old automatic gate with my Raspberry Pi. The signal tells me if the gate is OPEN->24 Vac or CLOSED->0 Vac. Raspberry Pi input are 3.3 Vdc tollerant. My first idea was to use a rectifier to get a DC signal and then use a voltage dividers to get the 3.3 Vdc. The second one was to use a octocoupler to achieve the same results. Has anyone any suggestion on what type of such devices should I use to achieve my goal?

Best regards

Ric

Comment: If you wanted to mesure the voltage, you would need an ADC, which would convert the voltage in digital outputs. 
But all that you need is just a binary output, i.e.: is there voltage? A rectifier could be simpler, but is better avoid the risk of damaging the sensible RPi GPIO pins. I would suggest a rectifier AND a optocoupler, or just an ac-capable optocoupler. They're simple, safe, and effective.

Comment: Riccardo, how quickly do you need to know if the AC is on and/or off? Can you allow seconds of time? Or must it be fairly quickly? There are really simple, really safe methods that slow (diode, resistors, capacitor) but easy. An opto is a fine method, too. An AC relay would work, as well. So would a couple of BJTs, a capacitor or two, and some resistors. And I'm only scratching the surface as there are so many ways to go. It would help a lot if you'd talk more about how you will use this signal, what you feel comfortable doing, and any space, time, weight, etc., restrictions you are aware of.

Comment: @jonk yes I do not speed, basically I just need to know if it is open or not (because I use a python script to open it and I want the user to know it is ALREADY open for some reason).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a slightly larger number of inexpensive multiple-sourced parts, you could consider using a part designed for this kind of application, the TI [ISO1211](https://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/an/slla382a/slla382a.pdf).

See Figure 3. I think values of Rsense = 560 ohms, Rthr = Rshunt = 1K and C = 100uF/50V would work, but check that yourself. It will run off the 3.3V Pi power supply.

[image]

You might want to use a [bridge](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/115/MB10F-1112781.pdf) rated at a bit higher voltage.

Comment: In the attached datasheet they are talking about 48V + AC signal does this work also for lower voltages?

Comment: The values I suggested should work, but check the calculations. Threshold should be around 12VAC RMS.

Comment: Aside from Figure 30, also see [this application note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla457/slla457.pdf?ts=1595626917904&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FISO1211). It's a boutique part. But not expensive and it does a lot. Nice! +1 because I just learned something else new.

Comment: with 1K in Rthr and Rshunt the 30V bridge rectifier will be only seeing about 17V peak so it should be fine. BAT54S seems a more convenient choice than BAT54C though.  or something newer like BAV99,235, or as you say the prefabricated bridge.